# Google Map in Visualforce Modalpopup

Tags: apex, visualforce, jquery, google-map, bootstrap

Hy i am new to salesforce and I am trying to display the google map in Bootstrap modal when the row is clicked . The modal shows up but google map does not display but when i click on Inspect element Map shows up. If any one can help me why the map is on showing up early when the modal is showing

The code of VF page is given below

```
<apex:page standardController="Property__c" extensions="PropertyController" standardstylesheets="false" showheader="false" sidebar="false" >

    <html>
        <head>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<style type="text/css">
      html { 
     height: 100% 
     }
body {
     height: 100%;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     }
#map-canvas {
     height: 450px; 
     width: 550px;
     } 




</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js" />
<script>
$('tr').on('click', function() {
});
$(document).ready(function() {
$("tr#tr_id").click(function() {
$("#leadID").text($(this).find("td.l_lati").text());
var address = $(this).find("td.l_id").text();
var agent =  $(this).find("td.l_agent").text();
var size =  $(this).find("td.l_size").text();
var status =  $(this).find("td.l_status").text();
var type =  $(this).find("td.l_type").text();
var lat =  $(this).find("td.l_lati").text();
var lng =  $(this).find("td.l_long").text();



        var map;
        var id=1;

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window,'load', initialize(id,lat,lng));

}); 
});


function initialize(id,lat, lng) 
{
var mapOptions ={ center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),zoom: 13};
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
loadProperty(id,lat,lng);
}

function loadProperty(id,lat,lng)
{
addMarker(id,lat, lng);
}

function addMarker(id, lat, lng) 
{
var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
{ 
position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
map: map,
title:'Hello'
}                              );

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(event) 
{
}
);
}
</script>
</head>


<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
     <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
        <apex:image url="{!URLFOR($Resource.Images, 'Images/RE.jpg')}" width="1340" height="130" />
        </div>

        <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="https://itroos-dev-ed--seit.na34.visual.force.com/apex/HomePage?core.apexpages.request.devconsole=1">Home</a> 
        </div>

        <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Property</a>
        </div>

        <div>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Detail</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://itroos-dev-ed--seit.na34.visual.force.com/apex/propertyInsertCode?core.apexpages.request.devconsole=1">Create</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
  </div>
</nav>
            <!-- container -->
        <div class="container">   


  <table class="table table-bordered " id="contacttable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Agent ID</th>
        <th>Size</th>
          <th>Status</th>
          <th>Type</th>
          <th>Latitude</th>
          <th>Longitude</th>
          <th>View Map</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <apex:repeat value="{!getProperty}" var="pro">
      <tr data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" id="tr_id">
        <td class="l_id" >{!pro.seit__Address__c}</td>
        <td class="l_agent">{!pro.seit__Agent_Name__c}</td>
        <td class="l_size">{!pro.seit__size__c}</td>
        <td class="l_status">{!pro.seit__Status__c}</td>
        <td class="l_type">{!pro.seit__Type__c}</td>
        <td class="l_lati">{!pro.seit__Location__latitude__s}</td> 
        <td class="l_long">{!pro.seit__Location__longitude__s}</td>
          <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-success">View Map</button></td>

      </tr>

        </apex:repeat>
    </tbody>
  </table>


<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">

             <div class="modal-header" id="a">
             <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
             <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Map</h4>
             </div>

              <div class="modal-body" id="b">
                    <div id="map-canvas" style="width: 500px; height: 500px">
                    </div>
              </div>


          <div class="modal-footer" id="c">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
    </div>
  </div>

    </div>



</div>
      <!-- modal popup end -->

</body>
</html>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: hey @Sheheri I am trying to replicate your issue can you pls share the record field values(i.e. seit__Address__c, pro.seit__Agent_Name__c, pro.seit__size__c, pro.seit__Status__c, pro.seit__Type__c, pro.seit__Location__latitude__s, pro.seit__Location__longitude__s)

Comment: seit__Address__c = Lalazar , 
seit__Agent__Id = A-00027 , 
size = 534 , 
Type = Commercial , 
LAtitude = 33.7380450 , 
Longitude = 73.0844880

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I am trying to use your code. Check this below example.

Modify your code based on below example.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" standardstylesheets="false" showheader="false" sidebar="false" >

    <html>
        <head>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js" />
    <script>
        var lat =  '18.9750';
        var lng =  '72.8258';
        var map;
        var id=1;
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#viewMapId").click(function() {
                setTimeout( function(){google.maps.event.addDomListener(window,'load', initialize(id,lat,lng));} , 400);
            }); 
        });


    function initialize(id,lat, lng) 
    {
        var mapOptions ={ center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),zoom: 13};
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
        loadProperty(id,lat,lng);
    }

    function loadProperty(id,lat,lng)
    {
        addMarker(id,lat, lng);
    }

    function addMarker(id, lat, lng) 
    {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
        { 
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
            map: map,
            title:'Hello'
        }                              );

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(event) {
        });
    }
</script>
</head>


<body>

    <button type="button" id="viewMapId" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">View Map</button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
               <div class="modal-header" id="a">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Map</h4>
               </div>
               <div class="modal-body" id="b">
                    <div id="map-canvas" style="width: 500px; height: 500px">
               </div>
               </div>
              <div class="modal-footer" id="c">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
</apex:page>
```

---

output

[image]

Comment: map is still not showing in modal but when i go to inspect element map starts loading

Comment: hey @Sheheri check my updated ans. you need update this. `$("#viewMapId").click(function() {
                    setTimeout( function(){google.maps.event.addDomListener(window,'load', initialize(id,lat,lng));} , 400);
                });`